# Uploading to Amazon S3 from web link

Tags: amazon-s3

I have huge amount of files on my old host... I would like to move all files to Amazon S3 since it seems very cheap. My internet connection at home is very slow, so I can't download them and upload it to amazon.

What I would like to do:
I have file X, located at: `http://mydomain.com/file.flv` and would like to move it to S3 without having to download it first.

Answer (score 5):

Why not spin up a micro instance on Amazon, then use that machine to transfer the files between the current host and S3. When the copy is done kill the VM and you stop paying for it.  This way you don't use any of your bandwidth just the old hosts and Amazon's.

Comment: thanks for the info... i haven't heard of micro instance... i will check it out...

Answer (score 0):

If your web host's FTP server supports it, you could try using FXP (File eXchange Protocol.  For transferring data between two FTP servers directly without downloading/uploading to your client).  Look for FTP clients that support FXP and S3 such as:  FlashFXP or Forklift (for OSX).